# How can I create a regex validation expression to allow this string?

Tags: regex, validation, matrix, latex, expression

I have this regex validation expression (thanks to ClasG and Marvel308):

[^((?P\begin{(?\w+)}\s*(?:-?\d+\s*(?:&\s*|\\\n))+\end{\g})|\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$|\$\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$\$|\[\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\]|\(\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\))$](https://regex101.com/r/Cq9QDX/5)

At the beginning of each row that contain the `-?\d`'s I would like to allow (but not require) the word "\left(". And at the end of each row that contain the `-?\d`'s I would like to allow (but not require) the word "\right)" How can I edit this validation expression to satisfy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that handles all your cases:

```
 (?:(?:\$\$?|\\[$[(]?)\s*|^)\\begin{(\w+)}\s*(?:-?\d+\s*(?:&\s*|\\\\\n))+\\end{\1}\s*(?:\$\$?|\\[]$)]?)?$
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Cq9QDX/4).

**Edit**

Here's a solution that only allows matching opening/closing *tags:

```
^((?P<matrix>\\begin{(?<token>\w+)}\s*(?:-?\d+\s*(?:&\s*|\\\\\n))+\\end{\g<token>})|\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$|\$\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$\$|\\\[\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\\\]|\\\(\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\\\))$
```

It uses a subroutine - `matrix` - to keep it a bit shorter.

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Cq9QDX/5).

**Here's an explanation:**

The *gut* of it is the part of it that recognizes the matrix:

```
\begin{name}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & -2 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 5 \\
\end{name}
```

This is done by the part

```
\\begin{(\w+)}\s*(?:-?\d+\s*(?:&\s*|\\\\\n))+\\end{\1}
```

which matches the a backslash followed by the literal text `begin`. Then it matches the *name* of the matrix inside curly brackets, capturing it into group one. Thereafter it matches any number of positive or negative numbers (`-?\d+`) followed by either an ampersand (&) or two backslashes and a newline (`\\\\\n`). These rows may repeat any number of times. Finally it matches the ending backslash and the name (captured to group 1) inside curly brackets `\\end{\1}`.

The first version allows (not mandatory) this to be preceded and followed by lines consisting of `$`, `$$`, `\(` and `\[`. No check is however made that the *enveloping* lines match each other.

The second version starts by testing for the *naked* matrix using the *gut* regex explained above, and doing so *stores* the regex as a subroutine named "matrix" - `(?P<matrix>`. The difference between the previous *gut* regex is that the *name* of the regex is stored in a **named** capture group - `token`. So the text for the end of the matrix is done with `\\end{\g<token>})` checking that the literal string inside the curly brackets matches the part captured into the group named `token`.

The test of the naked regex is then followed by alternations having the allowed surrounding lines with correct combinations of characters and using the subroutine `matrix` between them. E.g. the alternations

```
\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$
```

checks for a (one) dollar sign, optional white space, then the actual matrix (by *calling* the subroutine) followed by the matching terminating line, i.e. a single dollar sign.

Comment: fails many cases, take a look at https://regex101.com/r/tuc1cs/1

Comment: @marvel308 Agreed, but to have a single regex checking for all erroneous entries would make it unmanageable. That would be better handled in code IMO.

Comment: yes either that or use multiple regex to check, can't be achieved by a single regex

Comment: Well, multiple regexes can "always" be joined in to one by alternation, so in it really could be done in one.

Comment: @ClasG that is perfect! Would I be able to easily allow a specific word (example: "\left") where the user enters their numbers? So I would allow specific words and numbers where the -?\d occurs.

Comment: @ClasG Also I'm confused as to what the <matrix> and <token> attributes are used for. Can you explain what these are. I tried looking for information on these on regex101 but I still don't get it. Great work though!!! :) I edited my question also if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
\$\$\n\\begin{\w+}\n(\d+ & \d+ & \d+ \\\\\n){3}\\end{\w+}\n\$\$
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x72ras/1)

Comment: WOW you're good!!! One little change is that I would like to allow substituting "$$" ... "$$" for: "$"..."$", "\("..."\)", or even "\["..."\]". I've updated my question to display it more clearly.

Comment: I changed the expression to allow as many rows as possible: ^\$\$\n\\begin{\w+}\n(\d+ & \d+ & \d+ \\\\\n)+\\end{\w+}\n\$\$$

Comment: You can use 1 regex for the original problem, 1st update and 4th update. But for the 2nd and 3rd update they would have to be separate regex. I'll update my answer

Comment: I've changed your expression to allow more entries. Here is my current expression based on what you gave me: ^\$\$\n\\begin{\w+}\n((-?\d* & )+-?\d* \\\\\n)+\\end{\w+}\n\$\$$

Comment: @marbel308 oh yeah you just put quantifier \${1,2} right? But i know there is a way to add a back reference to allow either $$,$,\{, or \( isn't there?

Comment: ^(\${0,2})\n\\begin{\w+}\n((-?\d* & )+-?\d* \\\\\n)+\\end{\w+}\n\1$ would handle update 1 as well

Comment: check https://regex101.com/r/i1SadN/1

Comment: Will they be allowed to write two separate matrices like your regex link is displaying? I wouldn't want to allow more than 1 matrix. Otherwise that's great! If I can add a back reference to allow ([\{,\},\(,\),(\${0-2})]) somehow that would be the best!

Comment: no I used the multi line in regex101. for other updates you would need separate regex to check. can't be achieved by a single regex. Just change the stuff in the start and end locations and join by a or

Comment: I've used back references before though, why wouldn't it work in this case? Is it because I'm using different tags for opening and closing? Either way I can simply add a separate expression for each. Is there any flaws in doing so?

Comment: yes because of the different opening and closing tags, their is no way to handle cases like https://regex101.com/r/tuc1cs/1

Comment: the only problem I have with your expression is that I can open and close with any of the tags. I'd rather limit them to using one open/close tag type. (for example I can open with $$ and close with $) is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: (for example I can open with $$ and close with $) you want to allow this or disallow ?

Comment: No I would like to use the same opening tag for closing tags please.

Comment: ^(\${0,2})\n\\begin{\w+}\n((-?\d* & )+-?\d* \\\\\n)+\\end{\w+}\n\1$ would handle the $ cases